# Can FLV AAC stream be played in Android

Tags: android, audio, stream, aac

I'm trying to build a radio player and the client is providing a stream which is a FLV container with the audio being AAC

When I read the headers it shows up as audio/aacp.

I have tried all possible ways such as using the

1) Streaming through mediaplayer  (Does not work)

2) Use the NPR mode of using a proxy stream  (I get a broken pipe exception)

3) Play it in chunks ( Plays but I need the SDCard and the playback is not very great)

4) Use the GPL'd FAAD2 Library but I would have to pay the royalty fee

Can some one help me out on figuring this issue out.

The last option that I have is to have my client change the stream to mp3 container (which I know that it works)

Regards,
Hari