# Streaming AAC+ (inside FLV) on iOS using AIR

Tags: ios, actionscript-3, air, audio-streaming, internet-radio

For a streaming radio station, I have an AAC+ audio stream, inside an FLV container, delivered via HTTP.  An example URL is http://3023.live.streamtheworld.com/ALTROCK_S01A_AAC. I wrote a simple AIR app (using the latest AIR and Flex SDK's) to play this stream, and it works fine on PC and Android, but doesn't play anything when deployed to the iOS simulator or a device (i.e., the bytes are loaded but there is no sound).

This is similar to [Can FLV AAC stream be played in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4623526/can-flv-aac-stream-be-played-in-android), but for iOS.

I wanted to use AIR in this scenario, since I need to listen for the Cue Points in the FLV - and this is easy to do if you're playing Flash in a web browser, so AIR seems like the natural choice.  I have also looked at http://code.google.com/p/haxecast/ and https://code.google.com/p/project-thunder-snow/ but they all seem to use the same basic idea (parse the FLV using Netstream in "data generation mode" and feed the AAC+ data to a Video object) - and so they all hit the same wall on iOS.

I also came across [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12504447/actionscript-netstream-play-failed-ios-air-mobile?rq=1) which seems possibly related although it's not quite the same situation (e.g., it's not FLV).

Is AIR on iOS supposed to support this scenario- namely, streaming AAC+/FLV audio via HTTP?

**EDIT**: [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15770991/adobe-air-ios-live-streaming?rq=1) also appears to hit the same obstacle - so a lot of people are asking about this situation.  Anyone from Adobe have any insight?

Answer (score 1):

After much further research I've concluded that AIR on iOS just doesn't support this, and you have to build a native app (or at least use framework other than AIR) instead.